# Prove if $\{f_n\}$ converges in measure to f and g, then f = g a.e.

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

In my class notes there is a really brief sketch for this proof. Basically by the triangle inequality $\forall \epsilon > 0$ and $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$:

$m(\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}) \le m(\{x:|f(x)-f_k(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}) + m(\{x:|f_k(x)-g(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\})$

which implies $m(\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}) = 0$ so f=g a.e.

I was hoping to fill in some of the details, in particular, applying the limits in the definition of convergence in measure. To begin with, by triangle inequality if x is such that $|f(x)-g(x)|> \epsilon$ then $x \in \{x:|f(x)-f_k(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2})\cup\{x:|f_k(x)-g(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\})$ for any $k$. Then by sub-additivity we can get the expression I had in my notes:

$m(\{x:|f(x)-g(x)|>\epsilon\}) \le m(\{x:|f(x)-f_k(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\}) + m(\{x:|f_k(x)-g(x)|>\frac{\epsilon}{2}\})$

But to conclude the LHS = 0, it seems like I need to take the limit as $n \rightarrow \infty$ to utilize the definition of convergence in measure. Is it valid to just take the limit on both sides? Is any of this right? Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's correct (but given how late it is where I am at the moment, don't trust me completely!).

The statement $f=g$ a.e. is equivalent to $m(\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\})=0$; let's denote $N=\{x:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$. (So, we wish to prove that $m(N)=0$.)

You've shown, by taking the limit as $k\to \infty$ in the inequality you obtained, that $m(N_k)=0$ for all natural numbers $k$ where $N_k=\{x:\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|>\frac{1}{k}\}$.

Of course, $N=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} N_k$ and the countable union of sets of measure zero also has measure zero (by subadditivity of the measure).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is N also equivalent to $lim k \rightarrow \infty N_k$? I'm just curious if there would be a way to show it in terms of a limit as well? Admittedly, I don't see an obvious way. Thanks, I neglected to even think about the steps to show this thoroughly.

Comment: @Fractal20 Fractal, $N$ is a set and it's the union of the $N_k$ (for $k$ a natural number). So, I'm not sure what you mean by $\lim_{k\to\infty} N_k$; could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is valid to take the limit as $k\to\infty$ on both sides.

The left-hand side does not even depend on $k$, so this goes unchanged when taking the limit. The right-hand side is a sequence obtained by adding two convergent sequences together (both of them having limit $0$). So basically, the right-hand side is of the form $a_k+b_k$ with $\lim_k a_k=\lim_k b_k=0$ and hence $\lim_k (a_k+b_k)=\lim_k a_k+\lim_k b_k=0$ by e.g. [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_a_sequence#Properties).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! That is helpful.

Comment: +1 You explained an important point which directly answers the original question. It's also nice to see that we've got an excellent contributor to mathematics stack exchange in the area of probability theory; I've seen you around recently and I've come to observe the high quality of your answers! Thanks for your contributions, Stefan!

Comment: @AmiteshDatta: Thank you very much for your kind words :) +1 for your answer as well (which covers what I did not mention in mine).